# Making all Buttons in a vertical LinearLayout the same width

Tags: android, button, width

I am trying to make all the buttons in one horizontal LinearLayout the same width, based on one button which contains the longest text.

What i tried is to go through all the buttons in the layout and setting there size like this.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);

    for(int i = 0;i < layout.getChildCount();i++){
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof Button){
            if(!(v.getId() == R.id.widestButton)){
                ((Button) v).setWidth(findViewById(R.id.widestButton).getWidth());
            }
        }
    }
```

This does set all the buttons size, however, the size being set is not the size of the `widestButton`, its about 40% of it.

How do i make this work?

Comment: If you fixed your problem, you post post an answer with the solution and accept it.

Comment: This is what i tried.  Gave me this: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 4/7/2014 4:11:28 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, could have probably found it by googling.

Problem is, i was calling this code on the Activitys onCreate.
At this moment, the sizes of the Buttons are not calculated yet.

So i found the ViewTreeObserver, which is able to add a listener to be called when the Layout is done loading. The code i am using now is:

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            for(int i = 0;i < layout.getChildCount();i++){
                View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
                if(v instanceof Button){
                    if(!(v.getId() == R.id.widestButton)){
                        ((Button) v).setWidth(findViewById(R.id.widestButton).getWidth());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Which works perfectly fine.